# JDBC Informix Transaction Rollback

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, informix

On a maven project I am connecting to an informix database and I want to make a rollback when an exceptions occurs.
It seems that informix doesn't support rollback and I receive the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Not in transaction.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:416)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildIsamException(IfxErrMsg.java:401)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3096)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3368)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2292)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2217)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeRollback(IfxSqli.java:646)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.rollback(IfxSqliConnect.java:2124)
    at com.company.helpers.DBDriver.makeConnection(DBDriver.java:72)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

And here is the snippet in question. The exception occurs when calling `connection.rollback()`. For testing purposes, I called `rollback` on `try` clause.

```
     try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.username,this.password);
        LOGGER.info("Database connection successful.");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select FIRST 10 * from clients");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("id") + ", " + resultSet.getString("name"));
        }

        String sql = "UPDATE clients\n" +
                "\tSET idhost=5\n" +
                "\tWHERE id=9058;\n";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        connection.rollback(); //temporary to test rollback() 
        //connection.commit();

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        //connection.rollback();
        LOGGER.error("Errors occurred in database.");
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior when using JDBC autocommit. The Informix JDBC driver has auto-commit enabled by default. See
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html for a brief introduction to this.

So each statement you execute is automatically committed. The JDBC essentially executes a BEGIN WORK, EXECUTE, COMMIT WORK for each query and/or statement.

Thus when you explicitly execute a `connection.rollback()`, it will fail because all of your statements have been committed and you are technically not in a transaction.

You can turn this off with `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` then you can issue SQL statement `"BEGIN WORK"` to start a transaction and `connection.rollback()` to roll it back.

As Jonathan notes another quirk is if you use ANSI compatible database versus a normal logged database.  If it is ANSI, then you don't need the "`BEGIN WORK`" because ANSI databases are always in a transaction and a new one is started for you.

In general if you want to work with transactions you have to turn off auto-commit.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, for the extra knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very important information for dealing with JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

Informix has 4 types of database:

- unlogged
- buffered logging
- unbuffered logging
- (unbuffered logging and) MODE ANSI

An unlogged database does not support transactions. It may be that you've connected to an unlogged database. The buffered and unbuffered logging databases do not start a transaction until you execute BEGIN WORK (or just BEGIN). You might be failing because you didn't explicitly start a transaction. A MODE ANSI database automatically starts transactions and keeps them open until explicitly committed or rolled back, or when the session terminates, in which case they're rolled back.  You can always rollback (or commit) in a MODE ANSI database.

It's possible that the JDBC standard requires the 'MODE ANSI' semantics.  They're not hard to emulate — the driver simply has to send BEGIN WORK at appropriate points.

…Hmmm...

At the top of the exception stack trace, it says "Not in transaction".  That's error -255; there's also error -256 "Transaction not available".  If you were connected to an unlogged database, you'd get -256.  Since you get -255, you must be connected to a logged database, but you didn't explicitly start a transaction, so you can't roll it back.  Each statement is a self-contained transaction in the absence of BEGIN followed by COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

To fix, you'll need to start a transaction.  That might be as simple as:

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement;
int count = st.executeUpdate("BEGIN WORK");
st.close();
```

Or there may be an 'execute immediate' option that can be used instead.  The code is untested; I'm not a JDBC programmer and don't have a setup to test JDBC code.

The analysis is basically correct.  The suggested fix is not.  See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794203/15168) by [Brian Hughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8334122/brian-hughes) for a discussion of `autocommit` which provides the correct way to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the types of databases and the error message. As you said you are not a JDBC programmer so I don't want to ask anything code related, I just wanted to point out that I am initializing and starting a transaction with similar structure as the the example you provided, as you can see on the snippet on my question at the bottom.

Comment: Which line executes the BEGIN WORK?  I don't see a line that does that in the code.

Comment: Forgive me, I thought that BEGIN WORK was an example for a statement. The exception `SQLException` isn't happening with `rollback`. Thank you very much.